# Why select() doesn't respect timeout, especially in multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, select

We have client application that listens for UDP multicast feed and processes incoming data. It's portable and runs both on Windows and Linux. The main processing loop uses `select()` to wait for data, typically it's one or two UDP non-blocking sockets:

```
while(!stopRequested)
{
   fdset io;
   FD_ZERO(&io);
   FD_SET(sock, &io);

   timeval waitInterval = { 0 };
   waitInterval.tv_usec = 10000; // 10 milliseconds

   int r = select(sock + 1, &io, NULL, NULL, &waitInterval); 
   if(r == 0) // Process timeout
   else // Data or error processing
}
```

The code works pretty well but there is problem with timeout accuracy when no data is available.
We measured the time that actually is spent inside the `select()` during several of seconds of guaranteed idle (no data was sent) and the distribution is like this:

```
<1 usec     : 170 time(s)
<2000 usec  : 1 time(s)
<10000 usec : 11973 time(s)
<12000 usec : 6558 time(s)
<15000 usec : 64 time(s)
<20000 usec : 47 time(s)
```

There were no errors, `select()` always returned 0. So as we can see, there are several cases (170 times) when `select()` returned almost immediately, without waiting for any timeout.

So the question is why timeout is not respected in several cases? Similar results are obtained both for Windows (Win7 x64) and Linux (CentOS/RHEL6.0 x64).

Moreover, things became much worse when multithreading is used. When 2 threads are executing the code above (both calling `select()` for same socket, but `fd_set` and `waitInterval` are local objects), distribution of times inside `select()` is like this (for each thread):

```
<1 usec     : 13800827 time(s)
<10 usec    : 1639 time(s)
<100 usec   : 8660 time(s)
<1000 usec  : 16 time(s)
<12000 usec : 768 time(s)
<15000 usec : 39 time(s)
```

That looks like `select()` almost never respects timeout but returns 0 immediately in concurrent calls.

Is there any explanation of such confusing behavior? Common pitfalls of not re-initializing `fd_set`and `timeout` parameters are checked and this is not the case definitely.

Comment: What did you use to measure how long the timeouts took? Could you post a short self-contained example program that demonstrates this?

Comment: How do you do the measure?

Comment: What is your system HZ?  `grep 'CONFIG_HZ=' /boot/config-$(uname -r)`? This will tell your select timeout resolution, 1/HZ seconds.

Comment: `select()` is a system call if your resolution is 10 ms (and maybe is) your measure less than 10 ms have no sense.

Comment: is `waitInterval` initialized before every `select` call (like in the code sample you showed) ? What is it set to after the `select` call (on Linux) ?

Comment: I just had my test program run on CentOS 6 for a few minutes and not a single timeout below 10ms has happened. I'd say something is wrong with your measurement method. I've tried both single-threaded and between 2 and 6 threads.

Comment: On Linux clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, timespec) used to measure. System HZ is: CONFIG_HZ=1000

Comment: @Rost How are you measuring the time? Try it again with FIFO sched.

Comment: @Rost Try `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` instead of `CLOCK_REALTIME`. If you have a bad NTP daemon or some other weird thing setting the time in your system `CLOCK_REALTIME` might go backwards or do large adjustments. `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` will always go forward and won't adjust (well, it can adjust frequency, but not the time). If that doesn't solve it you have some other problem in your code, your system or you found a kernel bug. Because what you see should not happen (and still hasn't happened for me after 20 minutes).

Comment: @Art Actually you was right, the problem was wrong measurement (not the select() itself, but wrapping function). In several loops socket wasn't added to fd_set and select() wasn't ever called. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you sorted it out, but note that `select()` *will* return with no FD's ready before the timeout has expired if the process receives a signal.

Comment: @abligh Yes, of course, but in my case select() (OK, actually the wrapper) always returned zero. If signal received it shall return -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is nothing wrong with `select()`, it respects timeout correctly. Measurement was wrong - I measured not the `select()` call itself, but a wrapping function that actually checked `fd_set` and skipped `select()` call if empty. All times <10000 usec aren't related to `select()` call.

Probably this question shall be deleted as non-relevant.